# Div fadeIn and fadeOut on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I'm literally going crazy with this. I don't know why the `<div>` I want to fade in doesn't fade in.

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 520) {
    $("#bg").fadeIn();
} else {
    $("#bg").stop().fadeOut();
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">

    <div id="bg"></div>     
    <div class="logo"><img src="img/logoW.png"></div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/work/">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 11;
}

#bg{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    background: #262626;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 11;
}

.logo{
    position: fixed;
    width: 94px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 11;
}
.nav{
    list-style:none;
    text-align:right;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 11;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 6px 0 6px 0;
}
```

I tried different codes but I couldn't make it work, it's probably something really simple and I will end up feeling stupid.

I have a pure CSS parallax effect, can it interfere with scrolling ?

Full code [codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwwbja](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwwbja)

Comment: your page does'nt have enough content to actualy do a scroll, you need to more content to it.

Comment: I have content I just didn't put the code there, sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: take a look here, https://github.com/oussamaelgoumri/fixed_header, it add a fixed header to your page, as you scroll down, then remove it as you scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is missing its closing tags, it's supposed to look like this.

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 520) {
        $("#bg").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#bg").stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

You're also not closing your `img` tag properly. It's supposed to look like this.
`<img src="img/logoW.png"/>`

not like this.
`<img src="img/logoW.png">`

Comment: Img tags are void tags in html5 and do not need the slash to close them.[W3 syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) So that should not have made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

add more content to your page so you actually have a scroll to go with.

then update you script to

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 520) {
            $("#bg").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#bg").stop().fadeOut();
        }
    });
</script>
```